# Do Kotlin & Dagger belong together?

Tags: android, kotlin

Dependency Injection is perhaps the most powerful pattern of them all but I when combined with Kotlin I wonder if Dagger is reliable and most importantly debuggable enough to work on large projects. As just one example this instruction in gradle

```
  kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$rootProject.daggerVersion"
```

Yields a wonderfully long but useless message Cannot access NonExistent class:
Missing of course is such difficult information
1) The name of the class that is missing
2) Any information whatsoever about the point point in code where this reference is located.

Apparently it's a old issue reported in 2016 here:
https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/435

To solve this involves a two step process outlined here:
[ERROR : error.NonExistentClass Kotlin In multi module Dagger project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45099688/error-error-nonexistentclass-kotlin-in-multi-module-dagger-project)

Keep in mind you can have this error without multi-module situation.

This to me is prohibitive to using Dagger in a Kotlin app. Am I missing something or using the wrong version of something. I attached my whole gradle files below too!

```
      Error:17:18:39.263 [ERROR] [system.err] warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_7' from annotation processor '__gen.AnnotationProcessorWrapper_debug_android_arch_persistence_room_RoomProcessor' less than -source '1.8'
        17:18:39.263 [ERROR] [system.err] error: cannot access NonExistentClass
        17:18:39.263 [ERROR] [system.err]   class file for error.NonExistentClass not found
        17:18:39.263 [ERROR] [system.err]   Consult the following stack trace for details.
        17:18:39.267 [ERROR] [system.err]   com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for error.NonExistentClass not found

        17:18:39.363 [ERROR] [system.err] 1 error
        17:18:39.363 [ERROR] [system.err] 1 warning
        17:18:39.399 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
        17:18:39.403 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
        17:18:39.403 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
        17:18:39.403 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
        17:18:39.403 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
        17:18:39.403 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
        17:18:39.403 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
        17:18:39.403 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
        17:18:39.403 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
        17:18:39.403 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
        17:18:39.403 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
        17:18:39.403 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
        17:18:39.403 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        17:18:39.403 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        17:18:39.403 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
        17:18:39.403 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
        17:18:39.403 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        17:18:39.403 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        17:18:39.403 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        17:18:39.403 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        17:18:39.403 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
        17:18:39.403 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        17:18:39.403 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        17:18:39.403 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
        17:18:39.403 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
        17:18:39.403 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
        17:18:39.403 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
        17:18:39.403 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
        17:18:39.403 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
        17:18:39.403 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
        17:18:39.403 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
        17:18:39.403 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
        17:18:39.403 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
        17:18:39.403 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
        17:18:39.403 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        17:18:39.403 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        17:18:39.403 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
        17:18:39.403 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
        17:18:39.403 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:51)
        17:18:39.403 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:36)
        17:18:39.403 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.delegateAndHandleErrors(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:99)
        17:18:39.403 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:52)
        17:18:39.403 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:37)
        17:18:39.403 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:35)
        17:18:39.403 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:25)
        17:18:39.403 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.performCompilation(JavaCompile.java:198)
        17:18:39.403 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:183)
        17:18:39.403 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:120)
        17:18:39.403 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.factory.AndroidJavaCompile.compile(AndroidJavaCompile.java:95)
        17:18:39.403 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        17:18:39.407 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:173)
        17:18:39.407 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
        17:18:39.407 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
        17:18:39.407 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
        17:18:39.407 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        17:18:39.407 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        17:18:39.407 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
        17:18:39.407 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
        17:18:39.407 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
        17:18:39.407 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
        17:18:39.407 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   ... 27 more
        17:18:39.407 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
        17:18:39.411 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
        17:18:39.411 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
        17:18:39.411 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] 
        17:18:39.411 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED in 41s
```

Gradle File:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'


buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.7.0'
    }
}

kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.codingwords.sobrien.demo"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kapt { generateStubs = true }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$rootProject.architectureComponentsVersion"
    kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$rootProject.architectureComponentsVersion"
    compile "android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:$rootProject.architectureComponentsVersion"
    compile "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:$rootProject.rxjavaVersion"
    compile "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:$rootProject.rxandroidVersion"
    compile "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:$rootProject.rxkotlinVersion"

    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$rootProject.retrofitVersion"
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$rootProject.retrofitVersion"
    compile 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'
    compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$rootProject.okhttpVersion"
    compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$rootProject.okhttpVersion"
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'

    compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:$rootProject.daggerVersion"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$rootProject.daggerVersion"
    provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}


buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.60'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

Project level gradle

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            google()
        }
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }

    ext {
        minSdkVersion = 19
        targetSdkVersion = 26
        compileSdkVersion = 26
        buildToolsVersion = "26.0.2"
        supportLibraryVersion = "27.0.0"
        architectureComponentsVersion = "1.0.0-rc1"
        rxjavaVersion = "2.1.3"
        rxandroidVersion = "2.0.1"
        rxkotlinVersion = "2.1.0"
        daggerVersion = "2.11"
        retrofitVersion = "2.3.0"
        okhttpVersion = "3.9.0"

    }
```

Comment: For those looking for workaround in the meantime check this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45099688/error-error-nonexistentclass-kotlin-in-multi-module-dagger-project

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [kapt docs](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kapt.html), solution to `NonExistentClass` issue is to add this flag to your `build.gradle`:

```
kapt {
    correctErrorTypes = true
}
```