# error: incompatible types: NonExistentClass cannot be converted to Annotation @error.NonExistentClass()

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, kotlin-dokka

I am trying to generate Doka docs of my project. While generating I am getting an error like above. I have searched so many but could not able to get solution to this. I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45099688/error-error-nonexistentclass-kotlin-in-multi-module-dagger-project) link also. Here it is saying it might be a dagger related issue. I have tried these all solution also but not worked for me. I am posting here my all Gradle files for more clarification. if any one faced this issue or know the way to solve Please do comments.

**Project Gradle :**

```
 buildscript {
        ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.20'
        ext.dokkaVersion = '0.9.17'
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
            classpath "org.jetbrains.dokka:dokka-android-gradle-plugin:$dokkaVersion"
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:1.3.20"

            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

**App Gradle :**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.dokka-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xx.xxx.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled true
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.3"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    dokka {
        outputFormat = 'html'
        outputDirectory = "$buildDir/documentation"
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    signingConfigs {
        platform {
            storeFile file("../certs/platform.keystore")
            storePassword 'xxxxxxxx'
            keyAlias 'platform'
            keyPassword 'xxxxxxxx'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.platform
            zipAlignEnabled true
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.platform
            zipAlignEnabled true
            testCoverageEnabled = true
        }
    }

    androidExtensions {
        experimental = true
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation project(':library')
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.21'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.21'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.21'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.21'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.21'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.21'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.21'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1-alpha3'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1'
```

**library gradle :**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: "kotlin-allopen"
apply from: '../buildsystem/android_commons.gradle'

allOpen {
    annotation 'com.xx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxxx'
}
android {

    defaultConfig {
        versionName "1.0"
        buildConfigField "String", "xx", "\"xx\""
    }

    androidExtensions {
        experimental = true
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-alpha1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha3'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.21'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.21'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.21'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.21'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.21'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.21'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.21'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:23.3-android'

}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

> **Error**:- Task :library:kaptReleaseKotlin FAILED error: incompatible types: NonExistentClass cannot be converted to Annotation
>   @error.NonExistentClass()

Comment: Can you please add your full error message?

Comment: Task :library:kaptReleaseKotlin FAILED

error: incompatible types: NonExistentClass cannot be converted to Annotation
@error.NonExistentClass()

Comment: Add the additional flag to the build.gradle file to enable error type inferring in stubs:

kapt {
    correctErrorTypes = true
}

Comment: Check [this link](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kapt.html). Read **Non Existent Type Correction**.

Comment: Anything new after adding that kapt line?

Comment: error: incompatible types: NonExistentClass cannot be converted to Annotation
    @error.NonExistentClass().  I need help unable to solve this error even after trying every solution. I'm stucked.

Comment: Narrow it down to which code is failing, you can delete some code, run it again, if it fails, delete more. Eventually you'll arrive at an annotated code element that fails. It should give you (and us) more clue on what is going wrong.

Comment: If you using kapt you don't need to use annotationProcessor, error is generated by dagger-compiler or dagger-android-support but there is not enough info here to help