# Could not find protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin-1.0.0-windows-x86_64.exe (io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin:1.0.0)

Tags: kotlin, gradle, grpc, micronaut, protoc

I want to use protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin-1.0.0 from [protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.grpc/protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin/1.0.0) and I am getting

```
Execution failed for task ':generateProto'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':protobufToolsLocator_grpckt'.
   > Could not find protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin-1.0.0-windows-x86_64.exe (io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin:1.0.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/grpc/protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin/1.0.0/protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin-1.0.0-windows-x86_64.exe

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

The whole stacktrace is

```
C:\_d\toLearn\demo-grpc-jaeger>gradle clean build --stacktrace
> Task :generateProto FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':generateProto'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':protobufToolsLocator_grpckt'.
   > Could not find protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin-1.0.0-windows-x86_64.exe (io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin:1.0.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/grpc/protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin/1.0.0/protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin-1.0.0-windows-x86_64.exe

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':generateProto'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:38)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:41)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:372)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:359)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:352)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:338)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':protobufToolsLocator_grpckt'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultConfiguration.java:1282)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$1700(DefaultConfiguration.java:139)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.visitArtifacts(DefaultConfiguration.java:1259)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.visitContents(DefaultConfiguration.java:1252)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.visitStructure(AbstractFileCollection.java:326)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.lambda$calculateFinalizedValue$0(DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.java:249)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.UnpackingVisitor.add(UnpackingVisitor.java:61)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.UnpackingVisitor.add(UnpackingVisitor.java:94)
        at 
        
        ...
        
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:372)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:359)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:352)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:338)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin-1.0.0-windows-x86_64.exe (io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin:1.0.0).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/grpc/protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin/1.0.0/protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin-1.0.0-windows-x86_64.exe
        at org.gradle.internal.resolve.result.DefaultBuildableArtifactResolveResult.notFound(DefaultBuildableArtifactResolveResult.java:28)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository$LocateInCacheRepositoryAccess.resolveArtifactFromCache(CachingModuleComponentRepository.java:345)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository$LocateInCacheRepositoryAccess.resolveArtifact(CachingModuleComponentRepository.java:297)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.lambda$resolveArtifact$15(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:181)
        at 
        
        ...
        
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:41)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:372)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:359)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:352)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:338)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
4 actionable tasks: 4 executed

C:\_d\toLearn\demo-grpc-jaeger>
```

In case it add some usefull information, if I downgrade the version significantly it will cause a diferent error.

using implementation("io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin:0.1.2")

```
C:\_d\toLearn\demo-grpc-jaeger\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\main\com\tolearn\DemoGrpcJaegerServiceGrpcKt.java:35: error: incompatible types: NonExistentClass cannot be converted to Annotation
    @error.NonExistentClass()
```

which points the error to an autogenerated stub

[image: INtelliJ]

Here is the complete build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.4.10"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt") version "1.4.10"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen") version "1.4.10"
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "6.1.0"
    id("io.micronaut.application") version "1.2.0"
    id("com.google.protobuf") version "0.8.13"
}

version = "0.1"
group = "com.tolearn"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

micronaut {
    testRuntime("junit5")
    processing {
        incremental(true)
        annotations("com.tolearn.*")
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin:1.0.0")

    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-validation")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:${kotlinVersion}")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:${kotlinVersion}")
    implementation("io.micronaut.kotlin:micronaut-kotlin-runtime")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-runtime")
    implementation("io.micronaut.grpc:micronaut-grpc-runtime")
    implementation("javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-tracing")

    runtimeOnly("io.jaegertracing:jaeger-thrift")
    runtimeOnly("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic")
    runtimeOnly("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
}


application {
    mainClass.set("com.tolearn.ApplicationKt")
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("11")
}

tasks {
    compileKotlin {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "11"
        }
    }
    compileTestKotlin {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "11"
        }
    }


}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs("build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc")
            srcDirs 'build/generated/source/proto/main/grpckt'
            srcDirs("build/generated/source/proto/main/java")
        }
    }
}

protobuf {
    protoc { artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.14.0" }
    plugins {
        grpc { artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.33.1" }
        grpckt { artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin:1.0.0" }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all()*.plugins {
            grpc {}
            grpckt {}
        }
    }
}
```

The whole project can be cloned from [github](https://github.com/jimisdrpc/demo-grpc-jaeger.git)

So my straight question is: how add protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin-1.0.0?

A secondary question: I saw few examples using kapt(enforcedPlatform ... and implementation(enforcedPlatform ... like in this example bellow

```
dependencies {
    kapt(enforcedPlatform("io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:$micronautVersion"))
    kapt("io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-java")
    kapt("io.micronaut:micronaut-validation")

    implementation(enforcedPlatform("io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:$micronautVersion"))
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:${kotlinVersion}")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:${kotlinVersion}")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$kotlinxCoroutinesVersion")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-runtime")
    implementation("io.micronaut.grpc:micronaut-grpc-server-runtime:$micronautGrpcVersion")
    implementation("io.micronaut.grpc:micronaut-grpc-client-runtime:$micronautGrpcVersion")
    implementation("io.grpc:grpc-kotlin-stub:${grpcKotlinVersion}")
```

What is the purpose of "kapt(enforcedPlatform" and "implementation(enforcedPlatform"? Should my issue somehow related to missing one of enforcedPlataform ?

*** EDIT 1

Now I am getting

```
    Microsoft Windows [versão 10.0.18363.1256]
    (c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. Todos os direitos reservados.
    
    C:\_d\toLearn\demo-grpc-jaeger>gradle clean build --stacktrace
    
    > Task :kaptKotlin FAILED
    C:\_d\toLearn\demo-grpc-jaeger\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\main\com\tolearn\DemoGrpcJaegerServiceGrpcKt.java:35: error: incompatible types: NonExistentClass cannot be converted to Annotation
        @error.NonExistentClass()
              ^
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    
    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':kaptKotlin'.
    > A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
       > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)
    
    * Try:
    Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
    
    * Exception is:
    org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':kaptKotlin'.
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:200)
            at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:263)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:198)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:179)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:109)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:62)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)

 ...
            at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.incremental.IncrementalAptCache.updateCache(IncrementalAptCache.kt:26)
            at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.incremental.JavaClassCacheManager.updateCache(cache.kt:22)
            at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:86)
            at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing$default(annotationProcessing.kt:34)
            at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.Kapt.kapt(Kapt.kt:45)
            ... 31 more
    
    
    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
    
    BUILD FAILED in 8s
    8 actionable tasks: 8 executed
    
    C:\_d\toLearn\demo-grpc-jaeger>
```

With this build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.4.10"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt") version "1.4.10"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen") version "1.4.10"
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "6.1.0"
    id("io.micronaut.application") version "1.2.0"
    id("com.google.protobuf") version "0.8.13"
}

version = "0.1"
group = "com.tolearn"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

micronaut {
    testRuntime("junit5")
    processing {
        incremental(true)
        annotations("com.tolearn.*")
    }
}

//https://stackoverflow.com/a/55646891/4148175
//kapt {
//    correctErrorTypes true
//}

dependencies {

    //implementation("io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin:1.0.0")

    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-validation")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:${kotlinVersion}")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:${kotlinVersion}")
    implementation("io.micronaut.kotlin:micronaut-kotlin-runtime")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-runtime")
    implementation("io.micronaut.grpc:micronaut-grpc-runtime")
    implementation("javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-tracing")

    runtimeOnly("io.jaegertracing:jaeger-thrift")
    runtimeOnly("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic")
    runtimeOnly("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
}


application {
    mainClass.set("com.tolearn.ApplicationKt")
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("11")
}

tasks {
    compileKotlin {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "11"
        }
    }
    compileTestKotlin {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "11"
        }
    }


}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs("build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc")
            srcDirs 'build/generated/source/proto/main/grpckt'
            srcDirs("build/generated/source/proto/main/java")
        }
    }
}

protobuf {
    protoc { artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.14.0" }
    plugins {
        grpc { artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.33.1" }
        grpckt { artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin:1.0.0:jdk7@jar"}
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all()*.plugins {
            grpc {}
            grpckt {}
        }
    }
}
```

And gradle.properties

```
micronautVersion=2.2.1
kotlinVersion=1.4.10
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Starting from version 0.2.0, protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin is a Jar instead of a platform-dependent binary (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/grpc/protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin/1.0.0/). So in your `protobuf` configuration block, it should should be `grpckt { artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin:1.0.0:jdk7@jar"}`.

(Note if you do not specify the artifact extension, the protobuf plugin will pick the one based on your platform.)

Also, you probably do not need `implementation("io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin:1.0.0")` in your project's dependency.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunatelly now I am getting another error "... DemoGrpcJaegerServiceGrpcKt.java:35: error: incompatible types: NonExistentClass cannot be converted to Annotation
    @error.NonExistentClass()..." I added above more details

Comment: Should not be jdk11 or at least jdk8 instead of jdk7@jar at the end of grpckt { artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin:1.0.0:jdk7@jar"}?

Comment: No, protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin uses protoc-gen-grpc-java behind the scenes. Java plugin's minimum supported JDK version is 7. There isn't a jdk8 or jdk11 one at this moment (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/grpc/protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin/1.0.0/). The NonExistentClass error is irrelevant to code generation, it seems to be a quite common error for kapt, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45099688/error-error-nonexistentclass-kotlin-in-multi-module-dagger-project) might have information that can help.

Comment: Future readers may appreciate to know that I fixed NonExistentClass error by adding api("io.grpc:grpc-kotlin-stub:1.0.0")