# DefaultActivityViewModelFactory not found

Tags: android, android-viewmodel, dagger-hilt

After migrating the Hilt version from `2.33-beta` to `2.35` my project has stopped building with the error given below:

[image]

A txt version:

```
error: cannot access DefaultActivityViewModelFactory    
  class file for dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultActivityViewModelFactory not found   
  Consult the following stack trace for details.    
  com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultActivityViewModelFactory not found
```

A snippet of my `build.gradle` (project):

```
buildscript {
    ext.hilt_version = '2.33-beta'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.32"
        ...
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:$hilt_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

A snippet of my `build.gradle` (app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-parcelize'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    ...

    defaultConfig {
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments += [
                        "room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString(),
                        "room.incremental"   : "true"
                ]
            }
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    testOptions {
        execution 'ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR'
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
        dataBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    ...

    //DI
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03"
    implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-work:1.0.0-beta01'
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:$hilt_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt_version"
    kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0-beta01'

    // INSTRUMENTED TESTS
    ...
    androidTestImplementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:$hilt_version"
    kaptAndroidTest "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt_version"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.work:work-testing:2.5.0"

    //KOTLIN
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.4.32"

    //LIFECYCLE
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1'

    // WORK MANAGER
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.5.0"
}
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: With hilt you can initialize a ViewModel without a factory. Can you show your ViewModel's code!

Comment: I got the same issue. Removing this import seems to have fixed it for me `implementation  'androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03'`

Comment: @Rafsanjani thanks a lot. You are right. The `androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel` dependency was the problem. It was also redundant in the beta version. Feel free to write the answer ;)

Comment: @Rafsanjani Thanks a lot. I was getting a little different error, it was something like "Unable to process my.packages.SingletonC" but it also mentioned DefaultActivityViewModelFactory, and I don't even have any ViewModels or UI that use them yet (re-writing an app and just have the data layer, repo, and part of DI setup). Commenting out that lifecycle-viewmodel dependency fixed it.

Answer (score 263, accepted):

Removing the dependency on hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel causes the error to go away as it is no longer required in newer versions of hilt.
Simply delete this line from your app level `build.gradle` file if you have it.

`implementation  'androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:x.x.x'`

Comment: I removed and error gone, but when i added viewmodel dependency with ViewModelScoped  it throws errror like error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.example.smartbilling.ui.login.LoginViewModel cannot be provided without an Inject constructor or an Provides-annotated method.
  public abstract static class SingletonC implements BaseApplication_GeneratedInjector,
                         ^

Comment: @Akashkumar The docs over here might be helpful to you. It essentially shows you the recommended way of using the `ViewModelScope`

https://dagger.dev/hilt/view-model.html

Comment: @Rafsanjani, thanks! After removing this library I had to fix the error: `incompatible types: NonExistentClass cannot be converted to Annotation`. Your link to `ViewModel` helped me.

Comment: Didn't find this in the release notes google/dagger, or did we missing something? Btw, thanks a lot you saved our days!

Comment: Yes this solved my issue please flow android developer site for latest update i was using hilt version 2.44 at this time.

Answer (score 19):

**Remove below deprecated dependency:**

```
implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03"
```

**(It was deprecated since dagger-2.34 version)**

proof:
https://github.com/google/dagger/releases/tag/dagger-2.34

Also Try to upgrade your lifecycle version as below:

```
def lifecycle_version = "2.5.1"
```

add below lines after dependency section in **build.gradle(app)**:

```
kapt {
  correctErrorTypes true
}
```

**follow official documentation:**

https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android

https://dagger.dev/hilt/view-model.html

https://github.com/google/dagger/releases

Answer (score 17):

In your Build.gradle (:app), **remove** this line

```
implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03"
```

Your ViewModel should use `@HiltViewModel` & `@Inject` instead of `@ViewModelInject`

```
@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor() : ViewModel() { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Some dependencies were deprecated. Hence, you can modify `build.gradle (:app)` and project level `build.gradle` as shown below.

Additionally, you may look up the official source at: [Dependency injection with Hilt](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#kts)

`build.gradle (:app)`

```
plugins{
   ...
   id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
   id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

dependencies {
   ...
   // Dagger Hilt
   implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44.2")
   kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44.2")
}

kapt {
   correctErrorTypes true
}
```

`build.gradle (Project's root)`

```
plugins {
  ...
  id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.44" apply false
}
```