# dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultActivityViewModelFactory' could not be resolved- Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, dagger, dagger-hilt

**Detail Error**

*ComponentProcessingStep was unable to process 'com.example.daggerhilt.BaseApp_HiltComponents.SingletonC' because 'dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultActivityViewModelFactory' could not be resolved.*

**Application Class**

```
import android.app.Application
import dagger.hilt.android.HiltAndroidApp

@HiltAndroidApp
class BaseApp : Application()
```

**App Gradel file**

```
    @Suppress("DSL_SCOPE_VIOLATION") // TODO: Remove once KTIJ-19369 is fixed
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinAndroid)
    kotlin("kapt")
    id("dagger.hilt.android.plugin")
}
android {
    namespace = "com.example.daggerhilt"
    compileSdk = 33
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.daggerhilt"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation(libs.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.appcompat)
    implementation(libs.material)
    implementation(libs.constraintlayout)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.test.ext.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.espresso.core)

    // Coroutines
    implementation(libs.kotlinx.coroutines.android)
    implementation(libs.kotlinx.coroutines.core)

    implementation(libs.google.hilt.android)
    kapt(libs.hilt.compiler)

    implementation(libs.androidx.activity.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.hilt.lifecycle.viewmodel)

    implementation (libs.androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.ktx)
    implementation (libs.androidx.lifecycle.livedata.ktx)

    //retrofit
    implementation(libs.gson)
    implementation(libs.retrofit)
    implementation(libs.converter.gson)
    implementation(libs.logging.interceptor)


}
kapt {
    correctErrorTypes = true
}
```

** Project Level Gradel file**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
@Suppress("DSL_SCOPE_VIOLATION") // TODO: Remove once KTIJ-19369 is fixed
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinAndroid) apply false
}
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath(libs.gradle)
        classpath(libs.kotlin.gradle.plugin)
        classpath(libs.hilt.android.gradle.plugin)
    }
}
true // Needed to make the Suppress annotation work for the plugins block
```

** App Module file **

```
package com.example.daggerhilt.di

import com.example.daggerhilt.Network.ApiService
import com.example.daggerhilt.Network.HeaderInterceptor
import dagger.Module
import dagger.Provides
import dagger.hilt.InstallIn
import dagger.hilt.components.SingletonComponent
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun getBaseUrl() = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/"

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun getIsAddedToken() = true

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideHttpLoggingInterceptor(): HttpLoggingInterceptor {
        val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY) // Set the desired log level
        return loggingInterceptor
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideHeaderInterceptor(isAddedToken: Boolean): HeaderInterceptor {
        return HeaderInterceptor(isAddedToken)
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideOkHttpClient(
        httpLoggingInterceptor: HttpLoggingInterceptor,
        headerInterceptor: HeaderInterceptor
    ): OkHttpClient {
        val builder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        builder.addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor)
        builder.addInterceptor(headerInterceptor)
        return builder.build()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideRetrofit(okHttpClient: OkHttpClient, baseUrl: String): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideApiService(retrofit: Retrofit): ApiService {
        return retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java)
    }
}
```

** ApiService **

```
interface ApiService {
    @GET("posts")
    suspend fun getPost(): List<Post>
}
class ApiServiceImp @Inject constructor(val apiService: ApiService) {
    suspend fun getPost(): List<Post> = apiService.getPost()
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate questions check this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67256565/defaultactivityviewmodelfactory-not-found)

Comment: I have tried all the solutions coming same error .

Comment: check you haven forget to add annotation `@AndroidEntryPoint` before calling from Activity/fragment .

Comment: I have already added @A.Gun